# Django: "Model" matching query does not exist

Tags: python, mysql, django

For the record, I've scoured this website for similar answers, but I'm still beating my head against a wall trying to figure this out.

I'm using Django version 1.10, and I'm running MySQL as the database engine. I wish to simultaneously update a OneToOneField within a related model when saving information to my database (via my view), but an error is thrown "IndividualEmp" matching query does not exist.

Here are the models:

```
class IndividualEmp(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, db_column = 'name', primary_key = True)
department = models.CharField(db_column='department', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
emp_type = models.CharField(db_column='emp_Type', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'individual_emp'
    app_label = 'users'

class IndividualDetails(models.Model):
d_name = models.OneToOneField(IndividualEmp, models.DO_NOTHING, 
                              db_column = 'd_name', primary_key = True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'individual_details'
    app_label = 'users'
```

And here is my views.py file:

```
from users.forms import Register
from users.models import (Attendee, IndividualDetails, IndividualEmp)

# Create your views here.

def signup(request):
form = Register(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():

        obj = Attendee()
        obj_1 = IndividualDetails()
        obj_2 = IndividualEmp()

        obj.attendee_ID = form.cleaned_data['attendee_ID']            
        obj_1.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        obj_1.department = form.cleaned_data['department']
        obj_1.emp_type = form.cleaned_data['emp_type']
        obj_2.gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
        obj_2.email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        obj_3 = IndividualEmp.objects.get(name = 'name')

        request.d_name.individualdetails.individualemp = obj_3
        request.d_name.individualdetails.save()

        obj.save()
        obj_1.save()
        obj_2.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('users/signup')

else:
    form = Register()

return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form}))
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/signup/

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Stone\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Stone\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Stone\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\virtualenvs\env1\fireball\users\views.py" in signup
  25.             obj_3 = IndividualEmp.objects.get(name = 'name')

File "C:\Users\Stone\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Stone\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  385.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /users/signup/
Exception Value: IndividualEmp matching query does not exist.
```

Again, all I wish to do is have a field entry into IndividualEmp "name", and this same entry is passed to IndividualDetails "d_name" and save this to my database. Any help is appreciated, forgive me if I didn't post enough information.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing here. You already have an IndividualEmp object, in `obj2`. Why are you trying to query another one - and why are you using the literal string "name" as the query?

Comment: It's entirely possible that my understanding in utilizing Model.objects.get is incorrect-- I read other solutions where literal strings were used. I made another IndividualEmp obj (obj3) to "pass" the information to IndividualDetails. At least that was the idea. I've seen solutions where the syntax is Model.objects.get(id = field_name). In these cases, my models (I think) don't have a choice "id" to assign to any field. In fact, I attempted to use IndividualEmp.objects.get(id = name), but an error was thrown saying, "id" is not a choice.

Comment: Yoú're confusing fields with values. `name="name"` queries the field `name` with the literal string "name". Of course there will be no match. You need to query the field `name`with the *value* of the name you need to find. (Although I still don't understand why you need a new IndividualEmp). And, yes your models *do* have an id field as well. You really really need to go and do the basic Django tutorial.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and for the record, yes I've been following Django tutorials and reading other documents. I've encountered several other errors that I solved by following directions. At this point, I'm encountering this particular issue and I'm seeking clarification. So, if the solution is to grab the "value" from the "field", given my views.py, how do I retrieve the value from IndividualEmp object "name" and pass it to the IndividualDetails object "d_name"? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
 obj_3 = IndividualEmp.objects.get(name = 'name')
```

When you use the "get" method django expect in the database has one and only one record with that name. If there is more than one or none at all with that name, an exception will be thrown.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Comment: Thank you for replying. The field names in SQL table individual_emp are: "Name", "Department", "Emp_Type". Should I write the syntax as obj_3 = IndividualEmp.objects.get(name = 'Name')?